# Fortran write iteratively or store in an array then write

Tags: arrays, optimization, fortran, gfortran

Throughout many codes I write I need to put data in an external txt and have done so while it's generated (nest a write in the data producing loop). I've thought of writing values into an array here instead, then writing the entire array into a txt at once. Is this faster? How much faster given 'n' items? Say 'n' is of order(10) 6 to 12. Is it a bad idea to have such a large array?

Comment: Ignoring language-dependent stuff: writing in a loop is bound by latency (although OS and Filesystem might try some tricks), writing with a big buffer (in your case an array) is bound by bandwidth. So yes, in most cases the pre-collect then write approach will maybe 10-1000 times faster (just my probably very wrong approximation).

Comment: That's a good question. As @sascha said this method is much faster. Just a comment to make this faster. If you can preallocate the array, i.e. if you know the size of it, that would make the process even faster.

Comment: I disaggree, as long as you stay with txt files it will always be slow. Most of the time is spent at the coversion from binary to text.

Comment: @Vladimir What would you recommend I use? I plot my data with gnuplot. Is there a better way to externally store this data as well?

Comment: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node103.html

Comment: Seriously ?  *Throughout many codes* you've thought about this but never actually tested it ?

Comment: @High I've thought of it, but never tried it out since I figured it would of course be better. I just didn't know how it scaled nor have I needed to do it necessarily. I could write up something but was wondering if someone had the answer with finer details. Sorry :(